# How do I delete the last occurrence in a circular linked list? (java)

Tags: java, list

I want to make a method that deletes the last occurrence of a value given in an argument in a circular linked list.
I tried to do it and this is my approach:

```
public void deleteLastOccurence(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        Element prev = null;
        Element tmp = null;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return;
        
        if(this.rear.data == value) {
            this.head = this.rear = null;
            return;
        }
        
//      while(cur != this.rear) {
            while(cur.next != this.head && cur.next.data != value) {
                prev = cur;
                tmp = cur.next;
//              cur = cur.next;
            }
//          cur = cur.next;
//      }
        prev.next = tmp.next;
    }
```

But I don't think that I am deleting the last occurrence, because what if the value that I want to delete is right next to the same value.

Comment: How can a circular list have a *last* occurrence? How can you determine what comes first and what comes last?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - `this.head`

Comment: So this method can not be implemented in a circular linked list?

Comment: @Parasite that's not what I meant. I meant you need to define what it means for something to come first and come last in a circular structure. Imagine any two points on a circle. What does it mean for one to come first and one to come last?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The rear is the element before the head.

Comment: If you define the first node which has the value, then you can know the last node which has the same value.

Comment: If I consider I have only head, what would be wrong in my code (knowing that I updated the special case)?

Comment: @Parasite vsfDawg is right, you have to separate concepts of finding, deletion and checking for being empty by means of dividing your deleteLastOccurence method into divided parts.

Answer (score 1):

Separate finding the node from deleting the node.  The method is simplified to

```
public void deleteLastOccurrence(int value) {
  Element lastOccurrence = findLastOccurrence(value);
  if (null != lastOccurrence) {
    deleteElement(lastOccurrence);
  }
}
```

Assuming that a circular list means that the `head.prev` is the `rear` and the `rear.next` is the `head`. To find the last occurrence, start at the `rear` of the list and iterator towards the `head`.  The last occurrence is thus the first match you encounter.

```
private Element findLastOccurrence(int value) {
  if (isEmpty()) {
    return null;
  }
  Element current = rear;
  do {
    if (current.value == value) {
      return current;
    }
    current = current.prev;
  } while (current != rear);  // we're back at the rear with no match
  return null;
}
```

The `isEmpty()` and `deleteElement(Element)` methods are left as an exercise for the reader.